# What is the difference between sparse_categorical_crossentropy and categorical_crossentropy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

What is the difference between `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` and `categorical_crossentropy`? When should one loss be used as opposed to the other? For example, are these losses suitable for linear regression?

Comment: The main difference is your `targets`. Please check this post. https://jovianlin.io/cat-crossentropy-vs-sparse-cat-crossentropy/

Comment: @zihaozhihao quite good and clear explanation there. and can you answer my other question mentioned in post .

Comment: For linear regression problem, MSE loss is usually used.

Comment: the link of jovianlin.io does not works

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Simply:

- `categorical_crossentropy` (`cce`) produces a one-hot array containing the probable match for each category,
- `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` (`scce`) produces a category index of the *most likely* matching category.

Consider a classification problem with 5 categories (or classes).

- In the case of `cce`, the one-hot target may be `[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]` and the model may predict `[.2, .5, .1, .1, .1]` (probably right)
- In the case of `scce`, the target index may be [1] and the model may predict: [.5].

Consider now a classification problem with 3 classes.

- In the case of `cce`, the one-hot target might be `[0, 0, 1]` and the model may predict `[.5, .1, .4]` (probably inaccurate, given that it gives more probability to the first class)
- In the case of `scce`, the target index might be `[0]`, and the model may predict `[.5]`

Many categorical models produce `scce` output because you save space, but lose A LOT of information (for example, in the 2nd example, index 2 was also very close.)  I generally prefer `cce` output for model reliability.

There are a number of situations to use `scce`, including:

- when your classes are mutually exclusive, i.e. you don't care at all about other close-enough predictions,
- the number of categories is large to the prediction output becomes overwhelming.

**220405**: response to "one-hot encoding" comments:

one-hot encoding is used for a category feature INPUT to select a specific category (e.g. male versus female).  This encoding allows the model to train more efficiently: training weight is a product of category, which is 0 for all categories except for the given one.

`cce` and `scce` are a model OUTPUT. `cce` is a probability array of each category, totally 1.0. `scce` shows the MOST LIKELY category, totally 1.0.

`scce` is technically a one-hot array, just like a hammer used as a door stop is still a hammer, but its purpose is different. `cce` is NOT one-hot.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect: sparse_categorical_crossentropy still expects a one-hot encoding for the prediction.

Comment: This answer is just entirely wrong. How is this upvoted and accepted? The model output is still one hot encoded; it is just the true value that is stored as an index.

Comment: I updated the answer to be a little clearer.  The criticisms are accurate but orthogonal to the OUTPUT of cce and scce.

Comment: What does the `[.5]` mean? That's the most confusing part.

Comment: Yes, there's a some prior knowledge assumed in the answer.  Briefly, there is an unbounded set of categories for a target, each with a normalized probability that it is the target.  ALL possibilities in the set must sum to  `1.0`.   Thus `[.5]` means this category *generally* trains to be the target in about half the training runs.  Not great!  However, given five categories with a probability of `[.2 .5 .1 .1 .1]` then category 1 (from 0) is the best guess.  The higher the category value the more likely it is the match.  I can't say if .5 equates to an accuracy of 50%.

Comment: As what @mafu mentioned, shouldn't the output be a one-hot encoding instead of something like `[.5]`? This is consistent with @Bitswazsky 's answer too.

Answer (score 68):

I was also confused with this one. Fortunately, the excellent keras documentation came to the rescue. Both have the same loss function and are ultimately doing the same thing, only difference is in the representation of the true labels.

- Categorical Cross Entropy [[Doc](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#categoricalcrossentropy-class)]:

> Use this crossentropy loss function when there are two or more label
> classes. We expect labels to be provided in a one_hot representation.

```
>>> y_true = [[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
>>> y_pred = [[0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]]
>>> # Using 'auto'/'sum_over_batch_size' reduction type.  
>>> cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
>>> cce(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
1.177
```

- Sparse Categorical Cross Entropy [[Doc](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#sparsecategoricalcrossentropy-class)]:

> Use this crossentropy loss function when there are two or more label
> classes. We expect labels to be provided as integers.

```
>>> y_true = [1, 2]
>>> y_pred = [[0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]]
>>> # Using 'auto'/'sum_over_batch_size' reduction type.  
>>> scce = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
>>> scce(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
1.177
```

One good example of the sparse-categorical-cross-entropy is the fasion-mnist dataset.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(X_train_full, y_train_full), (X_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

print(y_train_full.shape) # (60000,)
print(y_train_full.dtype) # uint8

y_train_full[:10]
# array([9, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 7, 2, 5, 5], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: So scce features halfway through approximate values? Is this what `1.177` means? "Between 1 and 2, but most likely 1"?

Answer (score 20):

[From the TensorFlow source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cf0898dd4331baf93fe77205550f2c2e6c90ee5/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L3304), the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` is defined as `categorical crossentropy` with integer targets:

```
def sparse_categorical_crossentropy(target, output, from_logits=False, axis=-1):
  """Categorical crossentropy with integer targets.
  Arguments:
      target: An integer tensor.
      output: A tensor resulting from a softmax
          (unless `from_logits` is True, in which
          case `output` is expected to be the logits).
      from_logits: Boolean, whether `output` is the
          result of a softmax, or is a tensor of logits.
      axis: Int specifying the channels axis. `axis=-1` corresponds to data
          format `channels_last', and `axis=1` corresponds to data format
          `channels_first`.
  Returns:
      Output tensor.
  Raises:
      ValueError: if `axis` is neither -1 nor one of the axes of `output`.
  """
```

[From the TensorFlow source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cf0898dd4331baf93fe77205550f2c2e6c90ee5/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L4426), the `categorical_crossentropy` is defined as categorical cross-entropy between an output tensor and a target tensor.

```
def categorical_crossentropy(target, output, from_logits=False, axis=-1):
  """Categorical crossentropy between an output tensor and a target tensor.
  Arguments:
      target: A tensor of the same shape as `output`.
      output: A tensor resulting from a softmax
          (unless `from_logits` is True, in which
          case `output` is expected to be the logits).
      from_logits: Boolean, whether `output` is the
          result of a softmax, or is a tensor of logits.
      axis: Int specifying the channels axis. `axis=-1` corresponds to data
          format `channels_last', and `axis=1` corresponds to data format
          `channels_first`.
  Returns:
      Output tensor.
  Raises:
      ValueError: if `axis` is neither -1 nor one of the axes of `output`.
  """
```

The meaning of integer targets is that the target labels should be in the form of an integer list that shows the index of class, for example:

- For `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, For class 1 and class 2 targets, in a 5-class classification problem, the list should be [1,2]. Basically, the targets should be in integer form in order to call `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`. This is called sparse since the target representation requires much less space than one-hot encoding. For example, a batch with `b` targets and `k` classes needs `b * k` space to be represented in one-hot, whereas a batch with `b` targets and `k` classes needs `b` space to be represented in integer form.
- For `categorical_crossentropy`, for class 1 and class 2 targets, in a 5-class classification problem, the list should be `[[0,1,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0]]`. Basically, the targets should be in one-hot form in order to call `categorical_crossentropy`.

The representation of the targets are the only difference, the results should be the same since they are both calculating categorical crossentropy.

Comment: Tensorflow didn't complain when I used categorical_crossentropy with labels which were integers.  I would have expected an error.  Do you know why this works?