# traning MNIST model with proper hyper params in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

here is my code, i don't know why it gives me 0.3% accuracy

can anyone tell me what is the problem with this code?

```python
def train_mnist():

    mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])


    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)

    return history.epoch, history.history['acc'][-1]

train_mnist()
```

thanks in Adavnce

Comment: I guess that's not what you're amaing at, but it may help someone: A Convolutional Neural Net would be the best choice here.

Answer (score 1):

this will work! try this

```
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=loss_fn,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seem to be your loss function

Try this:

**Method 1**

You could use `categorical_crossentropy` as loss but the last layer should be

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax')
```

and then

```
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', 
              loss"categorical_crossentropy", 
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

**Method 2**

In your case, the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss need to define

```
tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True,name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
```

To understand the difference b\w these two see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58565394/what-is-the-difference-between-sparse-categorical-crossentropy-and-categorical-c)